# What is wrong with this project file for a ASP.NET 5 class library?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dnx

Today I quickly developed a new vNext class library, called `Sales.Data`, to act as the DAL for an MVC 6 UI project. I am somewhat out of my depth with ASP.NET 5, MVC6, DNX, and whatever else "vNext" includes, but eventually, with a lot of trial and error, and a lot of googling, I somehow managed to turn a standard class library into a vNext library, but now I cannot reference it from my xUnit DNX test project, nor from my MVC 6 UI project. The library uses NHibernate for very basic data access, just to establish proof of concept. This is what the bottom part of its `project.json' looks like, and whether it makes sense or not why it looks like this, at one stage my test project could at least reference the library, if not run a test. Now it cannot even reference it. What is wrong with this project's dependencies and frameworks configuration?

```
"frameworks": {
  "net46": {
    "dependencies": {
      "FluentNHibernate": "2.0.3",
      "log4net": "2.0.5",
      "NHibernate": "4.0.4.4000",
      "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel": "1.0.0-beta4",
      "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4"
    }
  }
},
"dependencies": {
  "System.Diagnostics.Tools": "4.0.0"
}
```

Comment: which version of ASP.NET 5 you use? `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel`  is renamed in `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration` (see [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25)) and `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json` to `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json`. Why you include almost all dependencies under `net46`  and not as common dependencies.

Comment: beta4 was a long time ago, you should be using rc1 by now. I recommend install [vs 2015 update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) if you have not already. Then re-install asp.net from https://get.asp.net/ and update your projects to use newer dependencies.

Comment: @Oleg That is simply the way Nuget inserted those references. I understand they look wrong, hence this question, but I try very hard to avoid using "Add Reference..." or manual edits when working with these projects. Granted, I may have made an edit I forgot, out of desperation, but it wouldn't have been the name or version, just the location.

Comment: @JoeAudette Those beta's were what Nuget gave me, and I am running 2015 Update 1, ASP RC1 for a while already. I have just run a "Repair" on ASP.NET RC Update 1, which I had installed, and am about to try a brand new project, and just copy my code over after adding packages again and checking their currency.

Comment: @ProfK: Many names of ASP.NET components will be changes in every new version. You can read about such renaming [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues) for example. Many new renaming expect us in RC2. Thus one have to modify the names. Do you tried to replace `ConfigurationModel` to `Configuration` (`Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel` to `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration` and `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json` to `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json`) and updates to version numbers to `"1.0.0-beta8"`? Could it help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted the error (if any) or explained why you believe you "cannot even reference it", however I suspect that its because the projects you are referencing from do not target the same framework.

You are targeting `net46` in the library above, when likely your MVC project is targeting `dnx451` or something similar.  If you change this project to instead (or also) target the frameworks your MVC project is targeting, you'll then be able to reference it.

Comment: I redid the class library, and it seems I may have fiddled more than I thought, but on adding dependencies to the new project, I found if I made the main framework `dnx46` and moved dependencies from other frameworks to that one, with some left in a framework agnostic `dependencies` node, the class library was loved and referencable by all and sundry.